# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to color: type=0x2 при API<21

Tags: java, android, xml, android-drawable, android-style

`java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to color: type=0x2`

Вываливается такая ошибка при тестировании на **API<21** (т.е. всё падает, хотя на 5+ версии андроида всё работает). Плюс `AndroidStudio` выводит предупреждение в файлах `xml-drawable`, но не выдаёт никаких подсказок. В чём беда -<s>кто виноват</s> и что делать?

Вот `xml drawable`:

```
<shape 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:endColor="?colorPrimary"
        android:startColor="@android:color/transparent"/>

</shape>
```

Comment: Вопрос - личная проблема; Ответ - вольный перевод решения с **en-SO**;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Согласно [en-SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13471695/3212712) проблема в том, что до `API 21` нельзя использовать аттрибуты-ссылки на цвета в `xml-drawable`, только ссылки на цвета из `@color`. Засим преобразовать надо приведённый файл так:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:endColor="@color/my_awesome_color_that_i_use_as_color_primary_in_my_awesome_theme"
        android:startColor="@android:color/transparent"/>

</shape>
```

Если же вам как и мне требуется использовать одну и ту же `xml-drawable` но с разными цветами для разных тем, то ничего не остаётся, кроме как:

1. Создать аттрибут-ссылку на `xml-drawable`

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <resources>
      <!-- по ссылке утверждают, что надо обязательно только lowerCase пользовать в названии -->
      <attr name="my_drawable" format="reference" />
   </resources>
   ```
2. Назначить ссылку на отдельный `xml-drawable` в этом атрибуте на каждую тему

   ```
   <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
      <item name="my_drawable">@drawable/my_drawable_for_this_theme</item>
   </style>
   ```
3. использовать этот аттрибут где надо. например фоном у `TextView`

   ```
   <TextView android:background="?my_drawable" />
   ```
4. Конечно же, не забыть создать по одному `xml-drawable` с конкретным цветом для каждой темы